# excluding element from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, element

I want to get the c array as result, but I don't know how:

```
import numpy as np
a = xrange(10)
b = np.array([3,2,1,9])
```

c is made of elements of a that are not in b:

```
c = np.array([0,4,5,6,7,8])
```

Comment: What is `np.xrange`? You mean `np.arange`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps a more straightforward solution is the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = xrange(10)
b = np.array([3,2,1,9])

c = np.setdiff1d(a,b)
```

Which results in:

```
In [7]: c
Out[7]: array([0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

You can find all of the set-like operations for numpy arrays in the documentation:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.set.html

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
b = np.array([3,2,1,9])

np.array(sorted(set(a) - set(b)))
# array([0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

**UPDATE**: works with `a = xrange(10)` too.

Comment: This is inefficient for large arrays. @JoshAdel's answer is a better way.

Comment: I would just say that having played around with the timings, @eumiro's solution is surprisingly efficient for a pretty wide range of array sizes. I would recommend benchmarking for your particular case to see which is better, also noting that `np.setdiff1d` has an option if both arrays contain only unique values, which can speed things up.